# How to access rstrui.exe from code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, system-restore

Please tell me how could i access system restore "rstrui.exe" from my c# code.

I tried by calling `C:\Windows\System32\rstrui.exe`;
But it is not accessible at all.

I need to call this function for redirecting my controls to System Restore.

thanks....

Comment: What exact code have you tried so far?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: yes i am able to call system backup and restore by this way.....

Answer (score 0):

You can access C:\Windows\System32 using the following property:

```
Environment.SystemDirectory
```

[Environment.SystemDirectory Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.systemdirectory.aspx)

You can run the executable using the following method:

```
Process.Start(Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "rstrui.exe"));
```

[Path.Combine Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx)

[Process.Start Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx)

UPDATE >>>

Ahhh... now I see your problem.

When accessing the `System32` folder from 32 bit code on 64bit Windows 7 and Vista (maybe Windows 8 too), Windows 'cleverly' changes that part of the request path to `SysWow64`. That is why you may have got a 'could not find path' error. In order to get around this, you can use the following:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\SysNative\rstrui.exe");
```

A more complete answer might be:

```
if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
{
    Process.Start(Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "rstrui.exe"));
}
else Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\rstrui.exe");
```

Comment: it is asking for definition of the keyword **Combine**.

Comment: I added a new link into my answer for `Path.Combine`.

Comment: Still not able to access the **rstrui.exe**.It is showing me the system32 folder only.

Comment: no it is a 32 bit windows 7 but the thing is that the keyword **combine** is not getting recognized and commands like **msconfig.exe** are also not executable from the code behind.please tell me the code for WPF.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are `using System.Windows.Shapes`. As can be seen from the `Path.Combine Method` link in my answer, Path is in the `System.IO` namespace. You don't 'have' to use that though... you could replace it with `string.Concat(Environment.SystemDirectory, @"\rstrui.exe")`. `Path.Combine` just concatenates the path segments with backslashes.

Comment: thanks for help but i am still not able to do this thing possible

Comment: Have you actually looked into the `System32` folder and checked that the `rstrui.exe` application is there? The only other thing that I can think of is that your user account doesn't have access to that folder.

Also, earlier you said 'Still not able to access the rstrui.exe. It is showing me the system32 folder only' What did you mean by 'It is showing me the system32 folder only'?

Comment: thank a lot but i found an other way to access this and it is now working fine. [from here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ad97bb81-0566-4eb9-b1e1-c591476a4958/cannot-start-msconfigexe-from-c-code)

Comment: Wow, really? I gave you that answer about 4 days ago, albeit with a shorter description. Either way, please create an answer and summarise your solution so that other users can find out easily. Please then mark your question as answered so that users do not waste time coming here to answer this answered question.

Answer (score 0):

I m running it all on a 64bit system, but still nothing works.
So I managed to resolve this:

```
IntPtr wow64Value = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            Wow64Interop.DisableWow64FSRedirection(ref wow64Value);
            ProcessStartInfo psi1 =
        new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");

            psi1.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi1.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi1.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            psi1.CreateNoWindow = true;
            psi1.Verb = "runas";


            Process ps1 = Process.Start(psi1);
            ps1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            StreamWriter inputWrite1 = ps1.StandardInput;

            // uses extra cheap logging facility
            inputWrite1.WriteLine("chcp 437");
            inputWrite1.WriteLine("rstrui.exe");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unabled to disable/enable WOW64 File System Redirection");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            // 3. Let the Wow64FSRedirection with its initially state
            Wow64Interop.Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(wow64Value);
        }
```

To enable it:

```
public class Wow64Interop
    {
        const string Kernel32dll = "Kernel32.Dll";

        [DllImport(Kernel32dll, EntryPoint = "Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection")]
        public static extern bool DisableWow64FSRedirection(ref IntPtr ptr);

        [DllImport(Kernel32dll, EntryPoint = "Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection")]
        public static extern bool Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(IntPtr ptr);
    }
```